The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process while deleting a file that is added to a imagelist and listview
I want to load the image files in a folder then add them to an imagelist then I will assign it to a listview to get thumbnail style on which item I click, it is shown in a picturebox. When I want to delete a file, I make the image property of the imagebox to null then I will remove the image item from listview and imagelist then I proceed to delete the file which I get the error "The process cannot access the file "path to image file" because it is being used by another process.
The code to load the images that fills the imagelist and listview:
 private void LoadImages(string path)
 {
     try
     {
         imageList = new ImageList() { ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit, ImageSize = new Size(194, 194), TransparentColor = Color.Transparent };
         listView.LargeImageList = imageList;

         IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);         

         foreach (string file in files)
         {
                 AddImage(file);
         }
         if (listView.Items.Count > 0)
         {
             string firstImage = listView.Items[0].ImageKey;
             selectedPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(firstImage);
             selectedPicBox.ImageLocation = firstImage;
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Program.EventLog.WriteEntry($"Scan-Loading scans : {ex}", EventLogEntryType.Error, 101);
         throw;
     }
 }

The code that adds images:
imageList.Images.Add(path, Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)), true, false));
    listView.Items.Add(path, file.Name, path);  

The code that deletes the images:
string path = listView.SelectedItems[0].ImageKey;
selectedPicBox.Image = null;
selectedPicBox.ImageLocation = null;

listView.SelectedItems.Clear();
listView.Items.RemoveByKey(path);

imageList.Images[path].Dispose();
imageList.Images.RemoveByKey(path);

File.Delete(path);


The way you're creating the Image is crazy. File.ReadAllBytes opens and closes a FileStream and reads the bytes from that. What's the point of doing that, loading those bytes into a MemoryStream and then reading them into a Image from that when you could just create a FileStream yourself and read them straight into an Image from there? You probably think your way is clever because you are doing it in one line but you shouldn't be, because that means that you are not disposing the MemoryStream. If you do it properly and close the MemoryStream, you can close the FileStream.

The problem is that you're doing this:
selectedPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(firstImage);

You are avoiding calling that method when populating the ImageList but you go and do it there. That will lock that file until you dispose that Image object., which you never do. You have this:
selectedPicBox.Image = null;

but that doesn't help because only stops displaying the Image. It doesn't dispose it. If you were going to do it that way, you'd need to do this first:
selectedPicBox.Image.Dispose();

You shouldn't be doing it like that though. This is crazy:
selectedPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile(firstImage);
selectedPicBox.ImageLocation = firstImage;

The whole point of the ImageLocation property is to be able to display an Image by providing just the file path and not having to create the Image yourself. You should be doing either one or the other, not both. If you want to avoid locking the file, you should be doing the latter.
In short, set the ImageLocation and DO NOT call Image.FromFile. Even then though, be sure to call Dispose on all objects that support when you're done with them. It may not be essential but it makes your app more efficient and can avoid some exceptions.

Quick and precise response! I commented all the image.fromfile and it worked. Thanks!

@MehdiForoughi, for future reference, you don't need to comment to say thank you and it is actually discouraged. SO is a Q&A site rather than a forum, so conversation is discouraged and we should stick to just the facts. If you find a question or answer helpful in general then you can up-vote them by clicking the arrow. If an answer solves the problem you posted in your question, you should accept it clicking the check/tick mark. This is all the thanks that's required and it will also boost both the other person's reputation and your own, opening up new permissions for you.
